# Excepcion java.util.NoSuchElementException: JAVA

Tags: java

Estoy en un proyecto y me esta saliendo el siguiente error.

Estoy llamando informacion de una tabla con el siguiente query

> SELECT id_cliente,nombre,razon_social FROM cliente

y accedo a la informacion por las siguientes clases

CLASE MODELO

```
public class cliente {

    private int id_cliente;
    private String nombre;
    private String razon_social;

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getRazon_social() {
        return razon_social;
    }

    public void setRazon_social(String razon_social) {
        this.razon_social = razon_social;
    }

    public int getId_cliente() {
        return id_cliente;
    }

    public void setId_cliente(int id_cliente) {
        this.id_cliente = id_cliente;
    }
}
```

CLASE DAO

```
public class gestionClientes {

    public ArrayList consultarCliente(){
        ArrayList<cliente> lstCliente = new ArrayList<>();
        queriesSQL queries;
        String sql;
        conexionBD dataBase;
        Connection con;
        PreparedStatement stmt;
        ResultSet rs;

        try{
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            dataBase = new conexionBD();
            con = dataBase.getConnection();
            queries = new queriesSQL();
            sql = queries.getConsulta("consultarCliente");
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
                cliente rcliente = new cliente();
                rcliente.setId_cliente(rs.getInt("id_cliente"));
                rcliente.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
                rcliente.setRazon_social(rs.getString("razon_social"));
                lstCliente.add(rcliente);
                System.out.println(lstCliente.add(rcliente));
            }
            try {
                dataBase.closeConnection(con, stmt, rs);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Logger.getLogger(gestionUsuarios.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            }

        }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex1) {
            Logger.getLogger(gestionUsuarios.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
        }

        return lstCliente;
    }
}
```

En esta clase estoy declarando un arrayList para almancenar toda la informacion, cuando la paso al servlet, deseo convertir ese array a un JSON array, pero me sale este error

> Información:   true
>   Información:   true
>   Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[mainServer]: Servlet.service() for servlet mainServer threw exception
>   java.util.NoSuchElementException
>       at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:862)
>       at Servlets.mainServlet.mainServer.processRequest(mainServer.java:1138)
>       at Servlets.mainServlet.mainServer.doPost(mainServer.java:96)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Esta es la parte de convertir el arrayLists a JSONArray

```
case "autocompletarCliente":
                JSONArray arrayCliente = new JSONArray();
                gestionClientes gAC = new gestionClientes();
                ArrayList<cliente> lsAC = gAC.consultarCliente();
                Iterator<cliente> iAC = lsAC.iterator();
                while (iAC.hasNext()) {
                    JSONObject jsonAC = new JSONObject();
                    jsonAC.put("id", iAC.next().getId_cliente());
                    jsonAC.put("nombre", iAC.next().getNombre());
                    jsonAC.put("razon_social", iAC.next().getNombre());
                    respuesta = "{result: 'ok', data:" + arrayCliente.put(jsonAC) + "}";
                }
                System.out.println(respuesta);
                JSONObject jLAC = new JSONObject(respuesta);
                response.setContentType("application/json");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                response.getWriter().write(jLAC.toString());
                break;
```

Cuando quito esta linea jsonAC.put("razon_social", iAC.next().getNombre()), todo funciona bien trae la informacion y lo transforma, pero cuando esta esa linea arroja la excepcion, agradezco la ayuda, la verdad hasta ahora estoy comenzando en la programacion. Gracias

Comment: ¿Faltaria la parte de convertir a JSON que es la que parece que te esta dando problemas?. Te he cambiado lo de DAO y MODELO que lo habias puesto al reves. Tambien he visto que estas añadiendo el cliente dos veces.

Comment: Primero gracias por tu ayuda, ya agregue lo que me pediste

Comment: De nada, para eso estamos.

Answer (score 1):

El problema viene porque estas haciendo `iAC.next` para cada propiedad y eso lo que hace es devolverte el siguiente elemento no el actual.

Cambia tu case por esto

```
JSONArray arrayCliente = new JSONArray();
            gestionClientes gAC = new gestionClientes();
            ArrayList<cliente> lsAC = gAC.consultarCliente();
            Iterator<cliente> iAC = lsAC.iterator();
            while (iAC.hasNext()) {
                JSONObject jsonAC = new JSONObject();
                cliente cliente = iAC.next();
                jsonAC.put("id", cliente .getId_cliente());
                jsonAC.put("nombre", cliente .getNombre());
                jsonAC.put("razon_social", cliente .getNombre());
                respuesta = "{result: 'ok', data:" + arrayCliente.put(jsonAC) + "}";
            }
            System.out.println(respuesta);
            JSONObject jLAC = new JSONObject(respuesta);
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write(jLAC.toString());
```

Lo que he hecho es recoger solo una vez el elemento con `cliente cliente = iAC.next();` y luego usar ese objeto cliente para sacar las propiedades

Comment: Muchas gracias! hice el cambio que hiciste y funciona, pero el objeto JSON genera de forma extraña mira: {result: 'ok', data:[{"id":19,"nombre":"Andres Gutierrez"},{"id":19,"nombre":"Andres Gutierrez"},{"razon_social":"PAM SOLUTION","id":20,"nombre":"Project Advance Management"},{"razon_social":"PAM SOLUTION","id":20,"nombre":"Project Advance Management"}]}, podrias explicarme porque?? no se si tenga que ver que el campo razon social esta vacion para el registro con ID 19

Comment: ¿A que te refieres exactamente?

Comment: Creo que ya lo solucione, Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, voy aprendiendo

Answer (score 0):

Segun lo que comentas en esta linea es el error:

```
jsonAC.put("razon_social", iAC.next().getNombre());
```

Veo que estas seteando en razon social de la siguiente forma:

```
rcliente.setRazon_social(rs.getString("razon_social"));
```

No deberias utilizar el metodo que corresponde al escribir en el JSON ? creo que seria de esta manera :

```
jsonAC.put("razon_social", iAC.next().getRazon_social());
```

Saludos !

Comment: Tienes razon, esta es una falla, ya lo corregi, gracias!!